# Sort on substring without other substring

Tags: python

Since yesterday I have been trying to sort my data and I need help because I can't do it.

I have

```
list_one = [
    ['HSubBbb'], ['Aaa'], ['Sub2XAaa'], ['BusXDdd'], ['CccSub2'], 
    ['BusBbb'], ['HBusXAaa'], ['Ccc'], ['HSub2XDdd'], ['CccSub'], 
    ['Sub2Bbb'], ['Bbb'], ['SubXAaa'], ['SubDdd'], ['CccBus']
]
list_two = ['Sub', 'Bus', 'Sub2']
```

I need

```
[
    ['Aaa'], ['Bbb'], ['Ccc'],
    ['SubXAaa'], ['HSubBbb'], ['CccSub'], ['SubDdd'], 
    ['HBusXAaa'], ['BusBbb'], ['CccBus'], ['BusXDdd'], 
    ['Sub2XAaa'], ['Sub2Bbb'], ['CccSub2'], ['HSub2XDdd']
]
```

I did several tests, for example

```
[x for y in list_two for x in list_one if y in x[0]]
```

Or

```
def my_list(t1, t2):
    def replace(s):
        s = s[0]
        for u in list_two:
            s = s.replace(u + 'X', '').replace(u, '').replace('H', '')
        return s
    t1 = replace(t1)
    t2 = replace(t2)
    return t1 < t2 

print(sorted(list_one, key=functools.cmp_to_key(my_list)))
```

Comment: According to what rules do you get the result from `list_one` and `list_two`?

Comment: List_one comes from an entered list by user, list_two is the second sort key. The first key is the absence of list_one in list_two. Sorry for my unclear explanation. I am very bad with English.

Comment: Do `H` and `X`  affect the sorting order?

Comment: @adamkwm Order no affected by H or X

Comment: There is too much key for my little brain. (1: absence of items from list_two) (2: order of list_two) (3: alphabetical order without [list_two, "H", "X"])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I define a function to handle the order of `list_two` first, then handle the remaining part after it. See comment in code for more details.

#### Edited:

1. Thanks for blhsing's comment, longer string should have priority in order, so variable `n` and `len(v) > n` is added to handle the length.
2. change `first` to `-1` so we don't need extra argument for `enumerate()`, and `first-1` in second part.
3. `keyf()` now receives two argument, so we can choose different order.

```
list_one = [
    ['HSubBbb'], ['Aaa'], ['Sub2XAaa'], ['BusXDdd'], ['CccSub2'],
    ['BusBbb'], ['HBusXAaa'], ['Ccc'], ['HSub2XDdd'], ['CccSub'],
    ['Sub2Bbb'], ['Bbb'], ['SubXAaa'], ['SubDdd'], ['CccBus']
]
list_two = ['Sub', 'Bus', 'Sub2']
list_three = ['Sub2', 'Bus', 'Sub']

def keyf(item, order):
    # order of list_two
    first = -1
    # keep track of length
    n = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(order):
        # does not break until going through the whole list to prevent substring case
        # longer string has priority
        if v in item[0] and len(v) > n:
            first = i
            n = len(v)

    # order of remaining
    second = item[0]
    for v in ("H", "X", order[first]):
        second = second.replace(v, "")

    return (first, second)

print(sorted(list_one, key=lambda x: keyf(x, list_two)))
print(sorted(list_one, key=lambda x: keyf(x, list_three)))
```

Output:

```
[['Aaa'], ['Bbb'], ['Ccc'], 
 ['SubXAaa'], ['HSubBbb'], ['CccSub'], ['SubDdd'], 
 ['HBusXAaa'], ['BusBbb'], ['CccBus'], ['BusXDdd'], 
 ['Sub2XAaa'], ['Sub2Bbb'], ['CccSub2'], ['HSub2XDdd']]

[['Aaa'], ['Bbb'], ['Ccc'], 
 ['Sub2XAaa'], ['Sub2Bbb'], ['CccSub2'], ['HSub2XDdd'], 
 ['HBusXAaa'], ['BusBbb'], ['CccBus'], ['BusXDdd'], 
 ['SubXAaa'], ['HSubBbb'], ['CccSub'], ['SubDdd']]
```

Comment: This happens to work for the test case only because `Sub2` comes after `Sub` in `list_two`. It would fail if `Sub` comes after `Sub2`.

Comment: Demo of the aforementioned failure: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ButterySharpFlashdrive

Answer (score 1):

For sorting the main sorting criteria is `list_two`, but in this group the value has to be removed for further sorting. Additionally sorting criteria like "Sub" and "Sub2" clash, because removing "Sub" for e.g. "Sub2Bbb" will leave us with "2Bbb". And of course the additional letters "H" and "X" have to be removed for sorting.

So we must test and remove the longest criteria first, but we have to find a way to keep the original order for sorting. `enumerate` can help with that.

```
sorted(list(enumerate(list_two)), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

This will give us

```
[(2, 'Sub2'), (0, 'Sub'), (1, 'Bus')]
```

If we loop over this list we handle "Sub2" before "Sub" and still know where the original position was.

Now put it all together.

```
list_one = [
    ['HSubBbb'], ['Aaa'], ['Sub2XAaa'], ['BusXDdd'], ['CccSub2'],
    ['BusBbb'], ['HBusXAaa'], ['Ccc'], ['HSub2XDdd'], ['CccSub'],
    ['Sub2Bbb'], ['Bbb'], ['SubXAaa'], ['SubDdd'], ['CccBus']
]
list_two = ['Sub', 'Bus', 'Sub2']

def sort_function(key):
    value = key[0]
    value = value.replace('X', '').replace('H', '')
    for entry in sort_criteria:
        if entry[1] in value:
            return (entry[0], value.replace(entry[1], ''))
    return (-1, value)  # default, no entry in sort criteria

sort_criteria = sorted(list(enumerate(list_two)), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
list_one.sort(key=sort_function)

print(sort_criteria)
print(list_one)
```

Result:

```
[['Aaa'], ['Bbb'], ['Ccc'], ['SubXAaa'], ['HSubBbb'], ['CccSub'], ['SubDdd'], ['HBusXAaa'], ['BusBbb'], ['CccBus'], ['BusXDdd'], ['Sub2XAaa'], ['Sub2Bbb'], ['CccSub2'], ['HSub2XDdd']]
```

You can add an output in `sort_function` to see what's going on. Before you return in the loop add `print(key, (entry[0], value.replace(entry[1], '')))` and you can see the original value and the key that is used for sorting.

Comment: The acepted answer had an error. I used `key=itemgetter(1)` for the sorting of the sort criteria. Due to the data in the example that worked. But the correct version has to check the length of the value, so it is `key=lambda x: len(x[1])`.

Comment: Outch:) thank you very much for this clearly explained demonstration. Now it's baffling how easy it was to d;)

Comment: Oh no, I don't think that's easy (just see the error I had to fix). I just had something similar some months ago and remembered how I solved that.

Comment: Correct with key=itemgetter(1), Size of list_two item is not significant.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate `list_two` to get a key for sorting order, and output the key if any of its item is a substring of a given string from `list_one`. Default to 0 if there is no match. To prevent a string in `list_two` from matching a string that should be matched by another string in `list_two` that it's a substring of (e.g. a string shouldn't be matched by `Sub` if it can be matched by `Sub2`, you can sort the list of keys in reverse order of the lengths of the strings. As for sorting Aaa, Bbb, Ccc and Ddd without H and X, you can remove H and X and the matching substring first with `re.sub` before sorting what remains as a secondary key in the tuple:

```
import re
list_one = [
    ['HSubBbb'], ['Aaa'], ['Sub2XAaa'], ['BusXDdd'], ['CccSub2'],
    ['BusBbb'], ['HBusXAaa'], ['Ccc'], ['HSub2XDdd'], ['CccSub'],
    ['Sub2Bbb'], ['Bbb'], ['SubXAaa'], ['SubDdd'], ['CccBus']
]
list_two = ['Sub', 'Bus', 'Sub2']
order = sorted(enumerate(list_two, 1), key=lambda t: -len(t[1]))
print(sorted(
    list_one,
    key=lambda l: next(
        ((i, re.sub(f'[HX]|{s}', '', l[0])) for i, s in order if s in l[0]), (0,)
    )
))
```

This outputs:

```
[['Aaa'], ['Ccc'], ['Bbb'], ['SubXAaa'], ['HSubBbb'], ['CccSub'], ['SubDdd'], ['HBusXAaa'], ['BusBbb'], ['CccBus'], ['BusXDdd'], ['Sub2XAaa'], ['Sub2Bbb'], ['CccSub2'], ['HSub2XDdd']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal which approaches my need. Words which do not contain any list_two item are in the first position and correctly sorted. But the others are not in the order of list_two :(

Comment: This is because `Sub` is also a substring `Sub2`, so strings that contain `Sub2` are matched by `Sub` too unfortunately.

Comment: You are right, I can do a first treatment to modify Sub2. But there is still a sort to be done. Aaa, Bbb, Ccc and Ddd.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that matches your expected output then.

Comment: Very condensed. :) I like this approach with `next` and the default value.